# How to translate "It's for the best"?

Tags: traducción

How does the phrase "to be for the best" translate into Spanish? My first thought was "es para lo mejor", but as this is fairly idiomatic in English I figured the translation might not be that literal.

---

**To be for the best**: used to say that a particular event may seem bad now, but might have a good result later:
 *I still don't want him to go but maybe it's for the best.*

---

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that the best options are

"Es lo mejor" o "ser lo mejor".

In your example:

> No quiero que vaya, pero quizá es lo mejor.

O también

> No quiero que vaya, pero quizá sea lo mejor.
>
> No quiero que vaya, pero será lo mejor.

Answer (score 0):

I would say

> Es para mejor.

In [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=best), "for the best" is translated to "para bien", but I have never used it.

Comment: Es para mejor is just a literal traduction, "es para bien" is the most accurate you could use

Comment: I disagree. depends on where you are. Here in Chile we use _Es para mejor_ and _Es para bien_ sounds weird.

Comment: Would 'es para lo mejor' make sense too?